# How to replace special character \ (backslash) to - (dash)

Tags: bash

How do I replace the special character \ (Backslash) to  - (Dash) in bash script.

I have tried sed but didn't work.

whoami

example - when I run whoami the output is DomainName\User

Current output - DomainName\User

Expected output - DomainName-User

Comment: Can you show us the command you tried in sed? It would be helpful for you to understand where you went wrong, so that the next time you try to do something similar, you can avoid repeating the error.

Comment: #!/bin/bash  
whoami > /tmp/user  
chmod 777 /tmp/user  
sed 's/\/-/g'  
user=$(</tmp/user)  
echo "$user"

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the escape character is missing

root@:~# echo "google\account" | sed 's/\\/-/'

google-account